# Cutting a string at first space

Tags: ada

I'm in the process of making my own package for an Ada main program. I read a string followed by an integer and another string and the problem is I need to cut the first string at sign of first space. I don't know how to do it and I've searched stack overflow only to find solutions in other languages.

My code right now in the package body is:

`Get_Line(Item.String, Item.X1)`

where X1 is an integer and String is the string. This works if you define the length in the type to match the exact length of your input but of course you want to be able to insert whatever you want and thus it doesn't work.

Can somebody point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Why do you need to make a package for an Ada main program? Most compilers need them to be parameterless library-level procedures.

Anyway, this might give you some tips.

```ada
with Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Integer_Text_IO;
procedure Agrell is
begin
   declare
      Line : constant String := Ada.Text_IO.Get_Line;
```

This is how to deal with reading a string of unknown length. You have to work out how to preserve it for future use (maybe use an `Unbounded_String`?)

```ada
      The_Integer : Integer;
   begin
      Looking_For_Space :
      for J in Line'Range loop
         if Line (J) = ' ' then
```

Everything from `Line’First` to `J - 1` is the string you wanted.

```ada
            declare
               Dummy : Positive;
            begin
               Ada.Integer_Text_IO.Get (From => Line (J .. Line'Last),
                                        Item => The_Integer,
                                        Last => Dummy);
            end;
```

OK, now we have `The Integer`...

```
            ...
            exit Looking_For_Space;
```

... and we’re done with the first line.

```ada
         end if;
      end loop Looking_For_Space;
   end;
end Agrell;
```

Comment: Or use `Space_Index : constant Natural := Ada.Strings.Fixed.Index (Line, " ");`

Comment: @JeffreyR.Carter yes, but I thought that might be distracting

Comment: Thanks Simon, I copied the code and it seems to compile. I wonder though, how do I call this procedure from my regular "Get" or "Get_Line" command? I tried Get(Line) and Get_Line(Line) but none of them work? - Oh and I need to make a separate package because its part of an assignment for school. I managed making the package by now but I had to make the user press enter several times in order to enter the data they were supposed to in order to cut the info at each enter, that instead of using proper formatting.